# Loading Entity definitions safely

Tags: java, thread-safety

I'm not quite sure I understood thread-safe correctly. I built the following registry:

```
@Service
public final class EntityDefinitionRegistry {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EntityDefinitionRegistry.class);

    private final HashMap<String, EntityDefinition> definitions = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    public EntityDefinitionRegistry() {
        Set<EntityDefinition> definitions = EntityDefinitionWrapperLoader.getDefinitions();
    }

    public @NotNull EntityDefinition getDefinition(@NotNull String entityName) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(entityName)) {
            throw new InternalErrorException();
        }

        EntityDefinition definition = definitions.get(entityName);
        if (definition == null) {
            throw new InternalErrorException();
        }
        return definition;
    }
}
```

This is initialized in the constructor and never changed again. The same is true for the contained objects. Their fields never change.

```
public final class EntityDefinition {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EntityDefinition.class);

    @NonNull
    private final String name;

    @NotNull
    private final String packageName;

    private final boolean cached;

    private final boolean abstraction;

    private final InheritanceStrategy inheritanceStrategy;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
    private EntityDefinition superEntity;

    private final CopyOnWriteArraySet<EntityDefinition> subEntities = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    private final CopyOnWriteArraySet<EntityField> entityFields;

    private final CopyOnWriteArraySet<EntityField> dtoFields;

    private final CopyOnWriteArraySet<EntityRelationField> relationFields;
```

Have I understood correctly that the final specification and therefore only read accesses are always thread-safe?

- I'm using Java 13.

Comment: I looked in to answering this question, but it turns out this is untested code that does not work. The class has a `private final` delcaration for `definitions` that initializes it with an **empty** HashMap, but the constructor shadows `definitions` with an incompatible HashSet that has values. As a consequence, the `getDefinition` will never get a non-null `definition` and will always throw an `InternalErrorException`. The code does not work.